# How to install Linux Wacom drivers on Lubuntu?

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, tablet, wacom, ubuntu-drivers

I need proper terminal commands to install [Linux Wacom Tablet drivers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/) on Lubuntu 14 (32 bit).

There are no clear step by step instructions for this particular OS and the installation fails every time when using typical instructions based on Ubuntu 14.